# How to convert tensors to a form acceptable for tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

**Task:** make a simple model for sentiment analysis. The pipeline has been passed, the data is presented in the form of nested lists. Problems start after trying to train the model.

```
history = model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs=50)
```

Since keras cannot make tensors from nested lists, we will convert everything into a list with numpy arrays, and then we will convert the outer list as well.

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    data[i] = numpy.asarray(data[i])

X = numpy.asarray(data)
```

This way we get: ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).

Specifying a type leads to a similar error

```
X = numpy.asarray(data, dtype=numpy.ndarray)
```

Okay, then let's try through ragged tensors

```
X = tensorflow.ragged.constant(data)
```

Now we get:

ValueError: Dimensions 32 and 35 are not compatible

**The question:** What exactly is the problem? The length of each nested array does not exceed 11, there are 32 arrays in total. Where the number 35 came from is completely incomprehensible. The largest word is 41 long, and there are also simply no other words more than 30.

Model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(gensim_to_keras_embedding(word2vec_model))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=Adam(0.001))
```

Summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding (Embedding)       (None, None, 300)         11849400  
                                                                 
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, None, 128)         219648    
                                                                 
 lstm_1 (LSTM)               (None, 64)                49408     
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 2)                 130       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 12,118,586
Trainable params: 269,186
Non-trainable params: 11,849,400
_________________________________________________________________
```

I will be grateful for any help.

**UPD:** Well, solution was simple: I forgot to remove some values from Y after pipeline, so now the sizes are equal. Thanks for advices.

After adding this

```
maxLen = 0
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    if len(data[i]) > maxLen:
        maxLen = len(data[i])

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    while len(data[i]) < maxLen:
        data[i].append(0)
```

nested lists are also the same size. But in fact, it leads to another error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'str\'>", "<class \'int\'>"})', '(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'str\'>"})'}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.int32'>"})
```

Guess I do something really stupid, but I still need help. Where could be the problem?

Comment: Ragged lists and numpy arrays do not work nicely, maybe not use ragged lists?

Comment: I don't know anything about the ragged tensors.  But for "regular" ones, the source array has to be a multidimensional numeric array - or list of lists that can be made into such.  That means all sublists of a nested list need to have the same length.  If they differ, the resulting array will be `object` dtype, which `tensor` says it can't handle.

Comment: `dtype=numpy.ndarray` is the same as `dtype=object`.  Such an array is little better than a list of lists (if not worse).  It doesn't matter whether it's a list of lists or a list of arrays.  If they differ in length the result will be `ragged`.